# StaleElementReferenceException and ElementClickInterceptedException in Python Selenium, when sending job applications to LinkedIn

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate one step job applications on LinkedIn

These are bugs I never saw coming. For the first job, the code successfully clicked the easy apply button, and saved the application.

However, the strange thing is, there where still errors as the code progressed did more repetitions:

1. For the second job, it said StaleElementReferenceException when my code tried to click the button again.
   [The code was supposed to click the blue "Easy Apply button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hRnQ.png)
2. I noticed that for the third application, it clicked the button successfully again. This was something that I found strange since the apply job buttons looked exactly the same. One of my code functions was to print the text of a button. This was when it failed to get back the text for the button, even though it worked in the first job.
   [The code was supposed to know that the text on the botton right blue button did not say "Next"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rar0d.png)
3. My Error Exceptions made the code go on to the third job, which had a ElementClickInterceptedException when it tried to click the save button.

I do not understand these two errors. Here is code: (It has some debug exceptions and breakpoints)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
 
url="Local drive disk/Users/pxl20/Documents/chromedriver"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=url)
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3610345204&f_AL=true&f_E=2&geoId=102257491&keywords=python%20developer&location=London%2C%20England%2C%20United%20Kingdom&refresh=true")
shop = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/header/nav/div/a[2]")
shop.click()
 

first=driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")
first.send_keys("qingliu188@yahoo.com")
 
first=driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
first.send_keys("lemon765")
 
first=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "btn__primary--large")
first.click()
 
stuff=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "job-card-container__company-name")
print(stuff)
print(type(stuff[0]))
for x in stuff:
    print("NEw attempt")
    x.click()
    try:
        stuff7=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "jobs-apply-button")
        stuff7.click()
        print("Form")
        #stuff7=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "artdeco-text-input--input")
        #print(stuff7)
        #stuff7[2].send_keys("8147693878")
 
        stuff7=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "button")
        stuff77=stuff7[1]
        print(stuff77.text, "The text")
        if stuff77.text=="Next":
            stuff7[0].click()
            reject=driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.artdeco-modal__confirm-dialog-btn")
            print(reject, "important")
            reject[1].click()
        else:
            stuff77.click()
            stuff7=driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "button")#"button.artdeco-modal__dismiss artdeco-button artdeco-button--circle artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view")
            stuff7[0].click()
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        print("broken2")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
 
time.sleep(1000000)
print(shop)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Is there anything I can change to solve the errors? Thanks!